# Hide HTML element with CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to set a HTML element  to ‚hidden‘ per CSS. Unfortunately the element does not react as if it was addressed by my code.
This has been my code:

```
.archive-header {
    display: none;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<header>...</header>
<div id="main" class="wrapper">
<section id="primary" class="site-content">
<div id="content" class="main">
<header class="archive-header"> <!-- hide this header element and everything inside -->
<h1 class="archive-title">...</h1>
</header>
...
```

**Update**
Sorry, my text-editor changed the quotationmarks, the original code uses the correct ones.

Comment: There is something strange about your quotation marks.  Try replacing „archive-header“ with "archive-header"

Comment: What quotes are those?

class="archive-header"

Comment: `„main“` and `"main"` are not the same

Comment: Are those special quote characters in your source or just here?

Comment: It works if you fix the quotes http://jsfiddle.net/fPJFL/

Comment: this sounds kind of a trolling to me XD, and guys don't tell him to replace the quotes in archive-header, replace them in all your code, those quotes are not correct, don't ever use them again if it's not a special case or you are on word and want them specifically

Comment: I updated the question, it doesn't work with the correct ones.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the right quotes `" "` or  `' '`

```
<div id="main" class="wrapper">
<section id="primary" class="site-content">
<div id="content" class="main">
<header class="archive-header"> <!-- hide this header element and everything inside -->
<h1 class="archive-title">...</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: Right, just replace your `„` and `“` quotes with `"`.

Answer (score 1):

you only can use " or ' for quoting attribute values.

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<header>...</header>
<div id="main" class="wrapper">
<section id="primary" class="site-content">
<div id="content" class="main">
<header class="archive-header"> <!-- hide this header element and everything inside -->
<h1 class="archive-title">...</h1>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<header class="archive-header"> <!-- hide this header element and everything inside -->
   <h1 class="archive-title">...</h1>
</header>
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace your quotes with real quotes: ", that should be enough